# C# WPF Custom Blinking Button

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I trying to create a button with color change effect at the background of button. But not working, kindly need u help.

Here is my code.

**XAML**

```
<Button Margin="0,11,160,0" Name="btnShowNotification"
Click="btnOpenCashdrawer_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
Style="{StaticResource NotificationOnButton}" 
VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="1" />
```

**App.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="NotificationOnButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="50000"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5" Width="45" Height="30">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Gray" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Border.Background>
                            <Image Width="19" Source="Images/turn-notifications-on-button.png" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                        RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to animate the Color property of a SolidColorBrush but you have set the Background of the Button to a LinearGradientBrush  so this won't work.

Try this:

```
<Style x:Key="NotificationOnButton" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="50000"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="5" Width="45" Height="30">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                            <GradientStop x:Name="sp" Color="Gray" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Image Width="19" Source="Images/turn-notifications-on-button.png" />
                    <Border.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" RepeatBehavior="Forever" AutoReverse="True"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetName="sp"
                                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color">
                                        <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Border.Triggers>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It animates the Color property of the GradientStop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below sample xaml for button blink animation.

**Xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"> 
<StackPanel>
    <Button Name="button1" Content="Animate Button!" Width="150" Height="30" Background="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Click="button1_Click" >
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Loaded">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard BeginTime="00:00:00" 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                Storyboard.TargetName="button1" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                            <ColorAnimation From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>        
</StackPanel>
```